# Automated way to find the center line of a 2d mesh?

Tags: bezier-curves

Given the simple 2d mesh pictured below, is there an automated way to create a curve or line that follows the middle of the mesh? I am able to do this manually with a bezier curve, but it would be helpful if there was an automatic way to do it for better precision.

[image]

Example of what I'm thinking (made by hand with a bezier curve):
[image]